# Capturing information about executed line of code from an exception

Tags: python, xpath, error-handling

I'm performing a series of `xpath` queries on an HTML document using the `lxml` library. As is commonly known, web site owners are often fickle and can change a page structure with little to no notice.

I have an existing work flow for capturing and handling errors. Essentially I have a custom log handler that captures the description of the error (where it occurred, etc.) as well as the original HTML document the error occurred with.

What I wish to do at this point is to begin programmatically documenting how many times a specific `xpath` query is failing. My current workflow is to comb through tons of logs and look for exceptions that deal with the various lines of codes that a particular query shows up on. I'm hoping I can optimize this.

```
try:
    result1 = document.xpath('query1')[0]
    result2 = document.xpath('query2')[0]
    result3 = document.xpath('query3')[0]
except LookupError:
    log.exception('Some more details', document)
```

**My question**: Is there a way to programmatically infer which query actually failed in the above try/catch block? Obviously a `LookupError` could have been generated by any three of the queries. How can I nail it down to just one without wrapping each one in a try/catch block?

**Edit for clarification**

There's actually a lot more underlying code to my blocks. A for-loop would not be efficient.

```
try:
    result1 = document.xpath('query1')[0]
    if some_condition:
        result2 = document.xpath('query2')[0]
    else:
        result3 = document.xpath('query3')[0]
    # More checking, etc.
except LookupError:
    log.exception('Some more details', document)
```

Comment: You cannot return to a try block once interrupted, no

Comment: You should think about writing some sort of loop that iterates over the queries.  Then you can write one `try` block inside the loop.

Comment: I wouldn't think you could return to a try block once interrupted. Rather, I was hoping for a method to derive the original failed query using the information generated in the exception block. Or perhaps there's a more intuitive way to pass that information before even entering the exception block.

Answer (score 1):

To find which query got error :

```
import traceback
print traceback.format_exc().split("\n")[2].strip()
```

Comment: Thank you, but in this situation there's more than just parsing in these blocks. Please see my edited post for details. With several checks being performed, a for loop would not be efficient. Also, my `log.exception()` call already captures all of the details from `traceback.format_exc()`. As stated in the original post, I'm not trying to just capture information on the error in a log file, I'm trying to programmatically deduce exactly which query failed on the fly.

Comment: if you can catch the error in except block, `traceback.format_exc().split("\n")[2].strip()` give which query got error